# Как интегрировать свое меню на чистом css в свою тему вордпресс?

Tags: php, wordpress

Делаю свою тему вордпресс с нуля.
Натянул главную страницу на Вордпресс, но появилась проблема с меню.

Т.е. у меня есть меню для сайта, выполненное на чистом css, делалось без использования плагинов и фреймворков.

Как это меню мне интегрировать в Wordpress?

Я знаю, что меню нужно зарегистрировать в functions.php, а затем прописать php код в файле header.php в том месте, где я хочу, что бы меню отображалось на сайте.

Но проблема вот в чем: по факту на сайте у меня три меню. Первое - для десктопа. При определенной ширине экрана оно скрывается с помощью display:none;

Когда десктопное меню скрывается, вместо него появляется кнопка гамбургер, при нажатии на которую, с левой стороны выдвигается боковое мобильное меню (второе меню).

Третье же меню - это мобильное языковое меню, которое выдвигается в мобильной версии справа. В десктопной версии это меню не видно.

Как мне правильно зарегистрировать и перенести на ВП все три менюшки, с сохранением всех стилей, которые были изначально им заданы при верстке?

Очень прошу помощи, поиск юзал - ничего не выходит.

Хочу подчеркнуть, я знаю как регистрируются и объявляются меню, но у меня не получается сохранить стилизацию этих менюшек, потому что вордпресс задает для элементов меню свои классы, вместо тех, которые использовал для стилизации я - это первая проблема. Вторая проблема - не понимаю как реализовать три разных меню по описанной мной технологии их функционала.

Comment: Не понимаю в чем проблема зарегистрировать 3 области для меню. А как сохранить свою разметку описано тут https://misha.blog/wordpress/nav-menu-walkers.html (см. часть "Переделываем меню при помощи волкера")